# How to permanently hide address bar when using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I've setup my Android app using the Quick Start directions using the latest PhoneGap build. When I launch the app in the Android emulator no address bar is present on the first page.  However, after I follow a link on the page to a second page, a new window launches and an address bar appears on the screen. From then on, the address bar is always visible.

I would like to know how to permanently disable that address bar for the lifetime of the application. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use the inapp browser plugin instead : org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

This plugin has neatly coordinated documentation, here is the detail

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md

To hide the address bar set the location to no, like below:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ChildBrowser PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser)

Comment: The documentation for that plugin is severely lacking.

Comment: see http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How-to-Create-a-PhoneGap-Plugin-for-Android